# Сложить два двоичных числа в форме с плавающей запятой

Tags: числа

Добрый день! Вопрос не к программированию, а больше к информатике. Помогите сложить два двоичных числа в форме с плавающей запятой.

а)

```
1 число. мантиса = 0,11101 порядок 101   
2 число. мантиса = 0,10101 порядок 011
```

б)

```
1 число. мантиса = 0,10010 порядок 010
2 число. мантиса = 0,10010 порядок 100
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Необходимо нормализовать порядок (выравнять), путем сдвига (в сторону большего числа)
2. Складываем мантисы
3. Если появляется перенос в мантисе, то увеличиваем порядок
4. Проверяем на полученные переполнения

пункт а)

**нормализуем:**

11101 / 101

10101 / 011 => 00101 / 101

**складываем:**

11101 + 00101 = +1 00010 / 101 => 10001 / 110

а со вторым сами разберетесь )

**p.s.** надеюсь правильно вспомнил )

**Upd**

собственно проверка:

11101 / 101 = **29**

10101 / 011 = **5.25**  => 00101 / 101 = **5**

11101 / 101 **+** 00101 / 101 **=** 10001 / 110 **=** 29 + 5 **=** 34

Ответ совпадает :)